# Use temp table instead of CTE for disposable purpose

Tags: sql-server, rdbms

1 As I known, CTE is more used for Query readability, not for performance.
Without talking about indexing, should we just use the temp table in all cases instead of CTE because there is no performance benefit anyway and temp table can achieve the same outcome as CTE?

2 But I still cannot get this: Temp Tables are physically created in the Tempdb database while CTE is not materialized. They are created in memory and got disposed of straight away after the next statement. 
Should we have fast better performance to access the same data in memory instead of materialized disk space?

Comment: It's hard to give you an exact answer without seeing an exact query.  Yes, using temp tables is one trick you can use to speed up performance.  This is especially true if you can index the temp table in a good way.

Comment: It seem to be like you are trying to ask something rather than asking!

Answer (score 2):

> Temp Tables are physically created in the Tempdb database while CTE is
>   not materialized. **They are created in memory** and got disposed of
>   straight away after the next statement.

This is wrong. `CTE` is not created, it's not a structure containing data. It's just like a `view` with the only difference that its definition is not saved as an object. As a consequence, it cannot be reused in other statements. It's just another form of writing a derived table.

For example, when you write

```
with USAcusts as 
( 
  select custid, companyname 
  from sales.customers 
  where country = N'USA' 
) 
select * from USAcusts;
```

It's the same as the code below:

```
select *
from
   ( 
  select custid, companyname 
  from sales.customers 
  where country = N'USA' 
   ) t
```

None of `CTE` or `derived table` is "created in memory", exactly like in `view` case,  SQL Server **expands the definition** of the table expression and **queries the underlying objects directly**.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for performance, always use temp table.

I will only use CTE for these reasons:

- very small and 1 time use temp data
- recursive query

Comment: To use it always, that's not quite right IMO. For small tables and result sets, and trivial use, a CTE might prove faster as it doesn't involve creating the temporary table and populating it.

Comment: That's just plain wrong. A temp table might have worst performance than a cte. There's no "one rule for all queries".

Comment: That is why i said i will only use it if it is a "very small and 1 time use temp data".